# Proving the p-series test using the mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives

So I am tasked with proving the p series test, i.e prove that for $r \in \mathbb{R}$, if $r>1$, then the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^r}$$

converges. I was given a hint on the problem, that reads:

Hint: To prove convergence, use the Mean Value Theorem on $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{r−1}}$
Doing that I saw that there exists $c\in [n,n+1]$ such that

$$\frac{1}{n^{r-1}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{r-1}} = \frac{r-1}{c^r}$$

I do not know where to go from here. I attempted a comparison and wasted much time with $\frac{1}{n^2+n}$ but then realized that only works for $r\geq2$. A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: This is most easily proven using the integral test, are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: It converges if $r>1$, not $r>0$.

Comment: @infinitylord Yes I am trying to avoid the integral test.

Comment: Cauchy condensation test works.

Comment: @Masacroso Just an exercise given by my professor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, we have
$$ \frac{1}{n^{r-1}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{r-1}} = \frac{r-1}{(n+\alpha)^r} $$
for some $0<\alpha<1$. But the right-hand side is decreasing, so $(n+\alpha)^{-r} \geq (n+1)^{-r}$. Hence
$$ \frac{1}{n^{r-1}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{r-1}} \geq \frac{r-1}{(n+1)^r}. $$
Now sum over $n$:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{r-1}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{r-1}} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{r-1}{(n+1)^r}. $$
But the sum on the left telescopes!
$$ 1-\frac{1}{(N+1)^{r-1}} \geq \sum_{n=2}^{N+1} \frac{r-1}{n^r}. $$
Hence, adding on the first term,
$$ \frac{r}{r-1}-\frac{1}{(r-1)(N+1)^{r-1}} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{1}{n^r}. $$
But the left-hand side obviously converges as $N \to \infty$, so so does the right.

Comment: first time I see this kind of proof for the convergence of the p-series. Amazing.

Comment: I agree. I was pretty pleased when I spotted how to do it. Presumably it's not used much because series often precede derivatives in analysis courses. Or possibly once one has the integral test, everything looks like an integral. It's quite Euler–Maclaurin-looking, too.

Comment: Beautiful proof. Thanks

Comment: @Masacroso This is the integral test in disguise

Comment: @user1952009 Indeed, which is why it produces exactly the same bound.

Comment: And so [$p$-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series) means $\zeta(p)$ ? In french we call it "série de Riemann"

Comment: @user1952009  Would this be more obvious if I proved the integral test? (Have not attempted that yet but I think it would be an interesting exercise.)